# jQuery's .css isn't adding background attribute to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As I'm trying to create a grid of images for my background, I need to be able to add the `background-image` attribute to the css of the `body` via jQuery, but it isn't working. The following code returns the correct value, but all I see in the end is a blank page.

```
<body>
<script>

$('body').css('background-image', function() {

    var position = 0,
        image = '';

    for(var x=1; x<=4; x++) {
        // 4 rows

        for(var y=1; y<=8; y++) {
            // 8 columns

            position++;

            image += 'url(img/bg/' + position + '.jpg)'; 
            if(x<=4 && y<8) { image += ','; } 

        }

    }

    console.log(image);
    return image;

});


</script>
```

As you can see, I'm doing the script work after the `body` tag is created, so my understanding is that I don't need `$(function(){})` to make things happen.

Can anyone see what's keeping this from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is wrong, so you're leaving out the `,` after every 8 URLs.

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').css('background-image', function() {

    var position = 0,
      image = '';

    for (var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
      // 4 rows

      for (var y = 1; y <= 8; y++) {
        // 8 columns

        position++;

        image += 'url(img/bg/' + position + '.jpg)';
        if (x < 4 || y < 8) {
          image += ',';
        }

      }

    }

    console.log(image);
    return image;

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The way I prefer to do things like this is to push the elements onto an array, then construct the string using `array.join(',')`.

Comment: This works great, and it took me a minute but I see how my logic was wrong in my `if` condition. Thank you for your reply!